# HTTP POST response is not deliverd properly rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, http-headers

I am working with rails application. In my development environment an API makes a HTTP POST request to my application and the application have to respond it accordingly. Every thing is working just fine up to receive the request and respond it with the status 200.

But the response is not delivered successfully to the requesting API.

Here is my code to respond the request

```
def mysomething
  if params[:secret] != webhook_secret
    response = {text: "Invalid webhook secret", status: 401}
  else
    if params[:event] == 'incoming_message'
      content = params[:content];
      from_number = params[:from_number];
      phone_id = params[:phone_id];
      result = {messages: {content: "Thanks for your message!"}}
    else
      result = {messages: {content: "invalid event"}}
    end
    response = {json: result.to_json, status: 200}
  end
  render response
end
```

Can anyone tell me where is the problem? why it is not forwarded to the API.

THANKS

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
render :json => response
```

Comment: i am not sure what is wrong with your api but this is working sure for me i just use that same code also {json: result.to_json, status: 200} in that you d not need result.to_json just use result and i am getting this response #{"json":{"messages":{"content":"invalid event"}},"status":200} at my local

Comment: i am also getting this on my local but its is not transferred to the external API. i am using"ngrok" to communicate with the API. do u have any idea about???